# jquery onclick tbody > tr > th.labelName, change associated all td's colors

Tags: jquery

I am new to Jquery, I have problem with dyamic pivot table,  tr > th.labelName, here labelName is dynamically generated, i have to change color of all td's associated with that perticular labelName. how can i do that ? Thank you

This is the code:

```
<table> 
    <tbody> 
         <tr></tr> 
         <tr></tr> 
         <tr> 
             <th class = "pvtRowLabel">Asia</th> 
             <td class = "pvtValue"> India</td> 
             <td class = "pvtValue"> Chaina</td> 
             <td class = "pvtValue"> Nepal</td> 
             <!--here i have to select td's based on the 'pvtRowlabel' value i.e "Asia" which is dynamically generated. --> 
         </tr> 
    </tbody> 
</table>
```

Comment: show some html code relating to your problem

Comment: no one is a magician here. you need to add supporting HTML, JS, CSS in order to let others help you.

Comment: <table>
     <tbody>
 <tr></tr>
 <tr></tr>
 <tr>
       <th class = "pvtRowLabel">Asia</th>
     <td class = "pvtValue"> India</td>
     <td class = "pvtValue"> Chaina</td>
     <td class = "pvtValue"> Nepal</td>  
<!--here i have to select td's based on the 'pvtRowlabel' value i.e "Asia" which is dynamically generated. -->
 </tr>
     </tbody>
 
</table>